# "enlarged" form and Aut(Spin(8))

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, spin-geometry

In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO(8)#Spin(8), it says that

"Sometimes Spin(8) appears naturally in an "enlarged" form, as the automorphism group of Spin(8), which breaks up as a semidirect product: Aut(Spin(8)) ≅ Spin (8) ⋊ S3."

Can someone explain what is the detailed main idea of this sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Wikipedia was incorrect, the corrected statement is

$$
Inn(Spin(n;\mathbb{R}))=Spin(n;\mathbb{R})/Z(Spin(n;\mathbb{R})) = 
SO(8;\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}/2 
$$

$$
Out(Spin(8;\mathbb{R}))=S_3
$$

$$
Aut(Spin(8;\mathbb{R}))=Inn(Spin(8;\mathbb{R})) \rtimes Out(Spin(8;\mathbb{R}))
=(SO(8;\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}/2 ) \rtimes  S_3 
$$
instead. someone should (I will) make correction to Wikipedia.